# SQL syntax error, don't know why

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to run a PHP script, but I keep getting this error whenever I run it.

Error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''id', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'username', 'password', 'hash', 'active'' at line 1
```

PHP:

```
<?php
require('includes/connect.php');

if($_POST['submit'] == true) {

    $firstname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']);
    $lastname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lastname']);
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    $hash = mysql_real_escape_string(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)));
    $active = mysql_real_escape_string(0);

    $query = mysql_query(" INSERT INTO users_main ( 'id', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'username', 'password', 'hash', 'active' ) VALUES ( '', '" . $firstname . "', '" . $lastname . "', '" . $email . "', '" . $username . "', '" . $password . "', '" . $hash . "', '" . $active . "' ) ") or die(mysql_error());

} else {

}

?>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post some of the sample queries that this is producing (echo the string you are building with some test values).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't quote column names with single quotes. MySQL uses backticks for quoting column and table identifiers.

[Some special keywords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html) need to be quoted with backticks if used as an identifier, but you have not used any of those.  None of your columns require quoting.

```
 $query = mysql_query(" INSERT INTO users_main ( id, firstname, lastname, email, username, password, hash, active ) VALUES ( '', '" . $firstname . "', '" . $lastname . "', '" . $email . "', '" . $username . "', '" . $password . "', '" . $hash . "', '" . $active . "' ) ") or die(mysql_error());
```